# MacBook Pro 13” (Mid-2012) Keyboard Input Enters Wrong Characters

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, keyboard

I’ve been given a MacBook Pro 13” (Mid-2012) laptop by a friend with an apparent dead hard drive. That was easily fixed (corrupt boot sector, reformat, reinstall, fine) but another issue presented itself – some of the keys when pressed produced either the wrong output (up arrow displays ‘9’, 9 key shifts cursor up one line); some display the correct character and a second, wrong one (2 key shows ‘2`’, 3 ‘3<‘, 4 ‘4]’, 1 displays ‘1’ but also attempts to increase volume); the F keys show what you would expect if you typed the number keys with the shift key depressed. I’m guessing this must be a hardware issue as I have already done the following:

- Changed the keyboard input settings
- Changed language settings
- Performed a full clean install on the supplied hard disk (HDD, 500GB)
- Performed a full clean install on a replacement hard disk (SSD, 1TB)
- Checked the keyboard ribbon cable and connector for dust and dirt and removed and reinserted it (no change to output produced)
- Restarted in Single User Mode (same keypress-character output discrepancy)
- Restarted in Recovery Mode (ditto)
- Attempted to start in Apple Hardware Test but that just starts Network Recovery (which I cannot connect to as my SSID contains characters I now cannot type on this keyboard!)

Just to be clear, an external USB keyboard works fine - but I would like this laptop to be used as a laptop, not some form of desktop replacement.

I doubt very much that this is a firmware issue as that would (surely?) be dealt with with OS installations (clean installed with Mohave, then upgraded to Sierra, then Catalina), so it boils down to this: is the keyboard itself faulty (and would this be resolved by a replacement) or could a controller chip have gone bad? Or could it be something else?

Comment: Has the battery swelled causing the keyboard issues?

Comment: If an external keyboard works fine, it usually means the internal one is broken.  No software glitch I have ever heard of causes the behavior you describe.

Comment: @SolarMike – The battery is in remarkably good condition, I don't think the laptop was under any heavy use

Comment: @TomGewecke – I suspect it needs a replacement keyboard but before I go down that route and buy a replacement keyboard plus attempt a precarious dismantling, I need to know if could be any other hardware issue.

Comment: How do you know that the battery is in "remarkably good condition"?

Comment: @SolarMike – It's still takes a good time to discharge and there's no physical swelling.